# load blue-imp jquery fileupload with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs, blueimp

I'm trying to load the jquery fileupload by [blue-imp](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)
with RequireJS.

I'm facing some problem while loading it. I tried the solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272773/requirejs-with-fileupload-plugins) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627203/requirejs-blueimp-fileuploader-only-loads-min-js-files-and-none-other) but none worked with my situation.

what i did in my `main.js` is

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : 'js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.0',
        jqueryfileupload : 'lib/jquery/jquery.fileupload',
        underscore: 'lib/backbone/underscore/underscore-min',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone/backbone-min',
    },
    shim : {        
    'underscore' : {
        exports : "_"
    },
    'backbone' : {
        deps : [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
        exports : "Backbone"
    },
    'jqueryFileUpload' : {
        deps : ["jquery"]           
    }
});
```

in my view when i'm laoding it

```
define(['backbone', 'jqueryFileUpload' ],
        function(Backbone, fileupload ) {

});
```

It's giving me error on console

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/AppUI/js/jqueryFileUpload.js?cmmn=1409151733588"`

Why it's picking backbone from its correct path and why jqueryFileUpload from baseURL directly?

I'm able to perform normal jquery operations like val(), append() but this one has dependency so i provided it.

I researched a bit more and found out the nested dependencies for fileupload.js which are jquery ui and widget. I also imported them  in my

```
        paths : {
            jquery: 'lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.0',
            jqueryUI : 'lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min',
            jqueryfileupload : 'lib/jquery/jquery.fileupload'
        },

       shim : {
           'jqueryUI' : ['jqueryUI'],
           'jqueryFileUpload' : {
                  deps : ["jquery", "jqueryUI", "jqueryIframetransport"],
                  exports : "jQueryFileUpload"
        }
}
```

Even after this i'm getting the same error. It's picking up the wrong path.

Any suggestions or approaches to proceed ahead?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use shim config with jquery fileupload for that reason ([shim config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim)):

```
//Remember: only use shim config for non-AMD scripts,
//scripts that do not already call define(). The shim
//config will not work correctly if used on AMD scripts,
//in particular, the exports and init config will not
//be triggered, and the deps config will be confusing
//for those cases.
```

Jquery file upload source files already use define (AMD) scripts! (look at jquery.fileupload.js)
Even so you can configure the requirejs dependencies this way:

top level project directory (bower compatible):

```
* app/
    - modules/
        - module.js
    - vendor/
        - jquery/
            - dist/
                - jquery.js
        - underscore/
            - underscore.js
        - jquery.fileupload-upload/
            - vendor/
                - jquery.ui.widget.js
            - js/
                - jquery.fileupload.js
                - jquery.fileupload.image.js.
                - ...
```

config.js:

```
var require = {
    "baseUrl": "/app/",
    "shim": {
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        }
    },
    "paths": {
        "jquery": "vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
        "jquery.ui.widget": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget",
        "underscore": "vendor/underscore/underscore-min",
        "bootstrap": "vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min",
        "tmpl": "vendor/blueimp-tmpl/js/tmpl",
        "load-image": "vendor/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image",
        "load-image-meta": "vendor/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-meta",
        "load-image-exif": "vendor/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-exif",
        "load-image-ios": "vendor/blueimp-load-image/js/load-image-ios",
        "canvas-to-blob": "vendor/blueimp-canvas-to-blob/js/canvas-to-blob",
        "jquery.iframe-transport": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport",
        "jquery.fileupload": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload",
        "jquery.fileupload-process": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process",
        "./jquery.fileupload-process": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process",
        "jquery.fileupload-image": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image",
        "jquery.fileupload-audio": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio",
        "jquery.fileupload-video": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-video",
        "jquery.fileupload-validate": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate",
        "jquery.fileupload-ui": "vendor/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui",
    }
};
```

module:

```
define(['jquery',
'tmpl',
'load-image',
'load-image-meta',
'load-image-exif',
'canvas-to-blob',
'jquery.iframe-transport',
'jquery.fileupload',
'jquery.fileupload-process',
'jquery.fileupload-image',
'jquery.fileupload-audio',
'jquery.fileupload-video',
'jquery.fileupload-validate',
'jquery.fileupload-ui'],

function ($, ...) {
```

Comment: Still relevant. Have an updoot!

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration inconsistently refers to your module with the name `jqueryfileupload` (in your `paths`) and with `jqueryFileUpload` (in your `shim`, and in your call to `define`). You could change your `paths` to use`jqueryFileUpload` so that it is consistent everywhere.

When you tell RequireJS about a module, you should refer to it by the same name everywhere. As far as RequireJS is concerned, `foo`, `FOO`, `Foo`, `FoO` are all different modules.