# blueimp jquery fileup with requriejs not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Hi I've already tried link from github and other SO questions. None of them solved my problem ([SO-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627203/requirejs-blueimp-fileuploader-only-loads-min-js-files-and-none-other) , [SO-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25531022/load-blue-imp-jquery-fileupload-with-requirejs), [github](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/How-to-use-jQuery-File-Upload-with-RequireJS)).

So Here is my code snippet:

```
require(
            [   'https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Templates/js/tmpl.min.js',
                'https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js',
                'https://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js',
                'upload/jquery.iframe-transport',
                'upload/jquery.fileupload-ui'
            ],function(){
                console.log("new action called ");
            }               
        );
```

in a folder "upload" i've below files:

- jquery.fileupload-audio.js
- jquery.fileupload-image.js
- jquery.fileupload-process.js
- jquery.fileupload-ui.js
- jquery.fileupload-validate.js
- jquery.fileupload-video.js
- jquery.fileupload.js
- jquery.iframe-transport.js
- load-image.js
- tmpl.js
- canvas-to-blob.js

After adding all above files, still in my console I've bunch of errors. out of them below two are actually doesn't make sense.

**js/jquery.fileupload-image.js : 23 'load-image-exif'**

**js/jquery.fileupload-image.js : 24 'load-image-ios'**

I can't find files with those names in official git repo. can anyone suggest an idea how to get it working (a fiddle would be a gret help).

Answer (score 1):

CH

I've manage to get the blueimp fileupload working after exploring every individual files. The problem is coming from require js dependencies, so if u are looking solution to use require js to load blueimp fileupload here is the solution.

1. Download latest blueimp fileupload release https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/releases
2. Remove all unnecessary files (All .html files, .json, .md, server folder, test folder and app.js from js folder). I just personally don't need those file, u can keep them if u want. I just like to keep thing tidy and clean. ^^

   [image: like these]
3. I've manually grabbed load-image-exif.js, load-image-ios.js, load-image-meta.js, load-image, tmpl.min.js and put them in vendor folder, where jquery.ui.widget.js is. So i cd to fileupload vendor folder and just curl grab these files like following

   ```
   curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/master/js/load-image-meta.js

   curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/master/js/load-image-ios.js

   curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/master/js/load-image-exif.js

   curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/master/js/load-image.js

   curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Templates/master/js/tmpl.min.js
   ```
4. have these path setting in ur require js config

   ```
   paths: {
       jquery: '//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min',        

       // redefined blueimp fileupload path
       "jquery.fileupload": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload",
       "jquery.fileupload-ui": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-ui",
       "jquery.fileupload-image": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-image",
       "jquery.fileupload-audio": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-audio",
       "jquery.fileupload-video": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-video",
       "jquery.fileupload-validate": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-validate",
       "jquery.fileupload-process": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process",
       "jquery.iframe-transport": "/jquery-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport",

       "tmpl": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/tmpl.min",
       "load-image": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/load-image",
       "load-image-ios": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/load-image-ios",
       "load-image-exif": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/load-image-exif",
       "load-image-meta": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/load-image-meta",
       "jquery.ui.widget": "/jquery-file-upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget",
   }
   ```
5. in ur app.js or main.js what ever u prefer just require either jquery.fileupload or jquery.fileupload-ui. For me I need to use the image preview and progress tracking and template engine so i'm requiring jquery.fileupload-ui

   ```
   define([
     'jquery',
     'jquery.fileupload-ui',
   ], function($) {
       $('#fileupload').fileupload({
           // work on ur magic here
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Seems I need you help. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650465/how-do-i-fix-orientation-upload-image-before-saving-in-folder-javascript